# Missing date after importing csv to MySQL using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

CSV date format is DD/MM/YYYY like this 16/11/2016. All the date become 0000-00-00 in MySQL. How to solve this differences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV date format to MySQL date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072295/csv-date-format-to-mysql-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

As of now I can think of two solutions to you problem:

1. Create a additional VARCHAR field to insert those values (like 16/11/2016), and create a TRIGGER on INSERT to update the date field by converting the string date to 'YYYY-mm-dd' type.
   These links may help

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php

2. In this step also, Create a additional VARCHAR field to insert those values (like 16/11/2016) and after import is done run a UPDATE query to update your date field using SET dateField = convertDate(dateFromSheet)